# What is the relationship between convergence uniformly, pointwisely, weakly, in $L^{\infty}$ norm and in $L^{p} $ norm?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces

What is the relationship between convergence uniformly, pointwise, weakly, in $L^{\infty}$ norm and in $L^{p}$ norm?

I am quite puzzled by so many convergences, can anybody tell me what is the relationship between them? Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.johndcook.com/modes_of_convergence.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables). Hope this answers your question